# Swing - paintComponent method not being called

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

i simply implemented class that inherits JPanel like below

```
public class Orpanel extends JPanel {

....
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setPaint(tpaint);
        g2d.fill(rect); 
    }
....
}
```

class Orpanel is loading image and adjusting it's own size.

here's question.

Calling JFrame's setContentpane(Orpanel's instance) makes it works fine 
but when i attach Orpanel to JFrame calling add() method instead of setContentpane (i know setcontentpane is not meaning attach.. anyway), it dosen't work.

finally figured out when i used add() method, Component that was added to JFrame doesn't call paintComponent() method. even though i call repaint() method manually, still paintComponent() method is not called.

did i miss something? 
any help will be appreciated!

thx in advance.
Jaeyong shin.

---

i added extra code.

```
public Test(OwPanel op) 
{
    super();
    Dimension monitor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    op.setBackground(Color.white);
    this.setBackground(Color.white);        
    this.setBounds(monitor.width / 2 - 200 , monitor.height / 2 - 200, 400, 400);       
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("test");      
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.getContentPane().add(op);
    //this.setContentPane(op);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.validate();
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            OwPanel op = new OwPanel("d:\\java_workplace\\img\\img1.jpg", 100, 100);
            OwLabel ol = new OwLabel("d:\\java_workplace\\img\\img2.jpg", 300, 50);
            Test tst =  new Test(op);
            tst.add(ol);
        }
    });
```

still doesn't work if setContentpane() method replaced to getContentpane().add().
don't be confused. Owpanel and Orpanel is same :)

Comment: can you provide the code where you added the `OrPanel` to the `JFrame`?

Comment: jFrame.getContentPane().add(jPanel) .... should work

Comment: did i miss something? sure you have to edit your post with posting the code that shows us your issue here are rulles http://sscce.org/

Comment: @SkeetOverFlow - no need for extensive typing, a simple frame.add is just fine ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your sample code, I see you have chosen NOT to use a LayoutManager, that's a very bad idea, but anyway, sicne you go this way, I see one reason for your `Orpanel.paintComponent()` not being called: it is probably not visible inside the frame!

If you have no `LayoutManager`, then you must explicitly set the size and location (through `setBounds()`) of all components you add to the frame.

It is likely you didn't do it, hence the size of `Orpanel` instance is probably 0 hence it never gets painted.

Comment: A better approach is to override the `getPreferredSize()` method in the custom component and **use** layout managers as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47605791/418556).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're just using the wrong methods. You should be doing this when adding a panel to a frame:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(panel) ;
```

Comment: I don't know, isn't it equivalent to `frame.add(panel);` ?

Comment: no, not needed (don't recall since when the cover method was added, could well be a decade ago ;-) Something else is wrong ...