# When trying to reprogram an Applet to an Application in Java, how do I properly call the paintComponent method?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I have recently been working on a Java applet. It was going to be a small applet, but I have since then decided to develop an application through Java. I am attempting to alter my code to be able to run the program as an application. My first question is: Is this a bad idea? Is it better to start from scratch?

My next question involves drawing on the window. If it is an okay idea to try to alter my applet into an application, I would like to know who to fix this problem I am having with Graphics. This is my main question. I am currently using the 'paintComponent' method to draw a simple string. I am doing this as a sort of test to make sure it was working. I am calling the 'paintComponent' method from a JPanel I create called graphicsPanel. I also have it printing out a string to notify me that the method was called. My trouble is, I cannot get these signs to show. I have done some searching about this common problem, but I have tried the suggested solution with no progress. Please let me know what I can do.

~Rane

Main Class: (It is in a sepertae class than ApplicationGame)

```
public class Application { // Rename to a better name later
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        ApplicationGame app = new ApplicationGame();
        app.runGame();  // Method that contains the init of the JFrame and the declaration of the graphicsPanel
        app.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Declaration of my Class (Frame):

```
public class ApplicationGame extends JFrame
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

More Frame Defining:

```
setSize(600,600); // All in the ApplicationGame class
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setTitle("Game - ALPHA 0.0.4"); // Rename
```

My graphicsPanel code:

```
JPanel graphicsPanel;

graphicsPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()) {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; // Suggested by Eclipse to insert this line

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString("Working...", 50, 50);
        System.out.println("Painted onto the panel");
    }
};
graphicsPanel.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
graphicsPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
add(graphicsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER); // In the class ApplicationGame (class extends JFrame)
```

Haven't solved my problem:

[Swing - paintComponent method not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398335/swing-paintcomponent-method-not-being-called)

[Why is paint()/paintComponent() never called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676187/why-is-paint-paintcomponent-never-called)

Comment: Have you called `setSize()` on your frame before your `setBounds()` call? And are you calling `setVisible()` before or after your setup code?

Comment: Yes I am. I will add this code now

Comment: @CPUTerminator `setBounds` will update the same information as `setSize` and all Swing components, except windows, are visible by default.  In fact, you should rarely if ever need to call `setBounds` or `setSize` on a component (other than a window), which probably a good sign that you are doing something wrong...

Comment: @MadProgrammer The issue is OP is using methods `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` in his/her `setBounds()` which could be 0 if no `setSize()`/`setBounds()` method was called prior. But this has been cleared from from OP's edit.

Comment: @CPU Based on the code snippet, it appears that the OP is relying on a layout manager (`add(..., BorderLayout.CENTER)`), which means `setBounds` and `setSize` will have no effect ;)

Comment: The process of painting in a `JAppelt` is the same for a "application". Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent subtle problems, you should ensure you migrate from the main thread to the [event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) before you use Swing components, by calling [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-) from main. That might not be the cause of this problem, however.

There is nothing wrong with how you are using `paintComponent`. It is called automatically. This demo shows a frame which displays the `graphicsPanel` correctly:

```
public class ApplicationGame extends JFrame {
    ApplicationGame() {
        JPanel graphicsPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()) {
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawString("Working...", 50, 50);
                System.out.println("Painted onto the panel");
            }
        };
        graphicsPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        add(graphicsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(ApplicationGame::new);
    }
}
```

Somewhere in your code that sets up and displays the frame, you must be missing a step, but you haven't shown all the necessary code.

Comment: I tried the SwingUtilties.invokeLater. That did not seem to help. You mentioned I did not show the necessary code. I have looked through my ApplicationGame class, but I do not see anything else of interest. What do you suggest as far as additional code?

Comment: [Something that can be run without having to manually assemble the pieces.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) That will avoid the guesswork about the behavior of the other code.