# paintComponent() in Java is not being called

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, paintcomponent

I am trying to draw a simple rectangle but I think the paintComponent method is not getting called.
Here is the code for the class with main method:

```
package painting;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Painting  {       

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jf;       
        jf = new JFrame("JUST DRAW A RECTANGLE");
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setLayout(null);
        jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jf.setSize(600,600);       
        jf.setVisible(true);
        Mainting maint = new Mainting();
        jf.add(maint);        
     }    
}
```

and the class with paintComponent()

```
package painting;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Mainting extends JPanel {
    @Override  
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawRect(0, 0 , 200, 200);
        System.out.println("haha");
        g.setColor(Color.red);
    }
}
```

What is the problem here, I cannot figure out...

Comment: Another tip for the future: it's better to call your JFrame's `setVisible()` method the last statement in your main method. This will let you avoid some unnecessary calls to `repaint()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the answers already provided might have resulted in the rectangle appearing, the approach was less than optimal. This example aims to show a better approach. Read the comments in the code for details.

Note that Swing/AWT GUIs should be started on the EDT. This is left as an exercise for the reader.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Painting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("JUST DRAW A RECTANGLE");
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // null layouts cause more problems than they solve. DO NOT USE!
        //jf.setLayout(null);
        jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        /* if components return a sensible preferred size, 
        it's better to add them, then pack */
        //jf.setSize(600, 600);
        //jf.setVisible(true); //  as mentioned, this should be last
        Mainting maint = new Mainting();
        jf.add(maint);
        jf.pack(); // makes the GUI the size it NEEDS to be
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Mainting extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED); 
        g.drawRect(10, 10, 200, 200);
        System.out.println("paintComponent called");
        /* This does nothing useful, since nothing is painted
        before the Graphics instance goes out of scope! */
        //g.setColor(Color.red); 
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        // Provide hints to the layout manager! 
        return new Dimension(220, 220);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your layout manager to eg. `BorderLayout`

so use

```
jf.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

and then add your component with some constraints

```
Mainting maint = new Mainting();
jf.add(maint,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```