# How can I use the Java graphics with Event Handling?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

What I am trying to do is when I click the button the rectangle needs to be drawn.

But I am having some confusions.
Here is the code :

```
package painting;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class Painting  { 

    JFrame jf ;
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Painting p = new Painting();
        p.runn();
    }
       public void runn(){

        jf = new JFrame("Try");
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jf.setSize(400,400);       
        jf.setVisible(true);

        JButton jb = new JButton("Click");
        jb.setBounds(200,200,100,60);
        jf.add(jb);
        //jf.add(jb,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        //jf.setLayout(null);       
        Handler handle = new Handler();
        jb.addActionListener(handle);
       }
        private class Handler implements ActionListener{
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
            Mainting maint = new Mainting();    
            jf.add(maint);
        }           


}
}
```

and the other class:

```
package painting;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Mainting extends JPanel {

    @Override  
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
             {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.fillRect(0,0,30,30);

            }    
}
```

Now, the problem is when I run this code a button appears covering up the entire screen and when I click on that, nothing happens.
I found out that that is because of layout manager is not defined, and when I try to set the Layout Manger to null, the button appears fine but when I click on that the rectangle does not appear (also that is because we can't use null layout manager to draw graphics).

And finally, when I try to set a layout manager, say - border layout -  the button appears as it should but how  compiler says it needs `int` parameters to be drawn and not directions!

Please help!

Comment: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Someone kindly did that for you in the last question, but don't expect others to be constantly doing for you, what you should be doing for anyone that reads the code. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/), like I posted as an answer to your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47605791/418556).

Answer (score 0):

use JPanel and then add button to it. setBounds() does not work good with Swing.Something Like this-

```
JButton button = new JButton(...);
JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
wrapper.add(button);
 frame.add(wrapper, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```